# Running `gem pristine --all` ... will improve the startup performance of Spring. (doesn't actually do it)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring-gem

I am running the Thin server for my Rails app locally. Every time I start it I receive the following message:

```
Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
```

Even after I run the command 'gem pristine -all' it takes a long time for the server to restart, and the message then appears again. Why so?

Answer (score 2):

`gem update --system` to get rid of the message works for me.

Comment: wooohooo!  been looking at the `gem pristine --all` warning for ages - thanks for posting

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Looking through the output from `gem pristine --all` I saw that several gems were being skipped with a message like

```
Skipped bigdecimal-1.1.0, it is bundled with old Ruby
```

I reinstalled those gems manually to get rid of the message

```
gem uninstall bigdecimal
gem install bigdecimal
```

Comment: Finally, a resolution! I freshly installed on a new computer and was still getting these errors. I just uninstalled all the gems that said "it is bundled with old Ruby" and after that `spring status` et. al. didn't give the warning anymore. Thanks!